# How to set icons for a list view items on android

Tags: android

I want to add some icons for every items in my list view in my android application.

```
mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar().getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
new String[] {
    getString(R.string.title_section1),
    getString(R.string.title_section2),
    getString(R.string.title_section3),
    getString(R.string.title_section4),
    getString(R.string.title_section5),
    getString(R.string.title_section6)}) {

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_grey));
    textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    return textView;
}
});
```

Should I add it on my `getView` function?

Comment: if you want to make icon on listview  then make a custome listview

Comment: there is no other solutions ?

Comment: please add your adapter code.

Comment: :o it's on the question !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ckpatel mentioned you can make a custom adapter see [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/) tutorial(preferred) or set **drawableRight** programatically to each of the textview just like you set the textcolor.

```
Drawable image =myContext.getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.ic_launcher);
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( null, null, image, null);
```

Comment: but it will display the same icon for the all items and these is not wath i want :/

Answer (score 1):

try this code for icon

```
TextView lbl = (TextView) convertView;
        lbl.setText(f.getTitle());
        lbl.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(f.getImage(), 0, 0, 0);
```